# How do I prevent a component from re-rendering after QR scan?

Tags: reactjs, render, qr-code, lifecycle

I've been building a QR scanning app in React and what it does it scans a code , and redirects a user to the QR-encoded URL after 2 seconds. It works fine.

Although right after the QR scan, I am rendering the decoded value in front, after this If I move my phone away from the camera, the value dissapears because the state has changed and thus React re-renders my component. I want this to remain the decoded URL even after I moved my phone.

here's my code:

```
QrScanner.js
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import BarcodeScannerComponent from "react-qr-barcode-scanner";
import React, { useEffect, useState} from "react";


const QrScanner = () => {
    const [data, setData ] = useState('');
    const history = useHistory();
    useEffect(() => {
      if(data === '') {
          return;
      }
  
      history.push(data);
      setTimeout(function () {
        history.go();
    }, 2000);
     
  })
      return (
  
      <>
          <BarcodeScannerComponent
              width={500}
              height={500}
              onUpdate={(err, result) => {
                  if (result) {
                      setData(result.text);
                  }
                  else setData('');
              }}
          />
          <p>{data}</p>   <------ this flickers, I want this to remain data after the scanning has happened
      </>
      );
  }


  export default QrScanner
```

And app.js:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import QrScanner from './QrScanner';
import Modal from 'react-modal';

  const customStyles = {
    content: {
      top: '50%',
      left: '50%',
      right: 'auto',
      bottom: 'auto',
      marginRight: '-50%',
      transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
      border: '2px solid black'
    },
    overlay: {zIndex: 9999}
  };
  
  Modal.setAppElement('#qr-id');

  const ModalWrapper = () => {

    const [modalIsOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  
    function openModal() {
      setIsOpen(true);
    }
  

  
    function closeModal() {
      setIsOpen(false);
    }
  
    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={openModal}><i class="fa fa-qrcode"></i></button>
        <Modal isOpen={modalIsOpen}  onRequestClose={closeModal} style={customStyles} contentLabel="Scan Your QR code">
          <h2>Please Scan Your QR Code</h2>
          <div><QrScanner /></div>
          <button onClick={closeModal}>close</button>
        </Modal>
      </ >
    );
  }

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
       <ModalWrapper />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('qr-id')
);
```

Does anybody know how Can I achieve this? I heard about `React.memo()` but unsure if that's the right tool for the job

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you only want to update `data` when you first find a QR code.

Try this:

```
<BarcodeScannerComponent
   width={500}
   height={500}
   onUpdate={(err, result) => {
   if (result) {
    setData(result.text);
   }
 }}
/>
```

This will update the value every time you find a QR code, if you just want to update it once you can check the current value for data.

```
if (result && data === '') {
    setData(result.text);
}
```